# Is there an equivalent of NOLOCK table hint of MSSQL in Sybase 15.5 T-SQL?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I am writing an app that pull data from a sybase table rather frequently. Since I will not write any data back to the database, I want to increase the read performance by not holding data locks on the target table.

In MSSQL I can do it via table hint NOLOCK. Is there a equivalent in the Sybase T-SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me say that it's not recommended to use [NOLOCK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2009/04/06/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas.aspx).

I believe the locking hint you are looking for is `noholdlock` or `at isolation`, but the syntax varies depending on if you are trying to use it at the session level, the query level, or for specific tables within a query.

The full explanation can be found here in the [Locking and Concurrency Control](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00938.1502/html/locking/X39708.htm) documents from Sybase.